# Why does clojure allow single argument for lessthan (<) or greater than (>) operators/functions

Tags: clojure

Why does clojure allow single argument for lessthan (<) or greater than (>) operators/functions?
I was wondering why it is just returning 'true' instead of forcing at least 2 arguments?

Source:

```
(defn >
  "Returns non-nil if nums are in monotonically decreasing order,
  otherwise false."
  {:inline (fn [x y] `(. clojure.lang.Numbers (gt ~x ~y)))
   :inline-arities #{2}
   :added "1.0"}
  ([x] true)
  ([x y] (. clojure.lang.Numbers (gt x y)))
  ([x y & more]
   (if (> x y)
     (if (next more)
       (recur y (first more) (next more))
       (> y (first more)))
     false)))
```

Comment: The docstring pretty much explains it already. `>` is not a binary operator in clojure's definition. It stands for *monitonically decreasing order* that does not mandate at least 2 operators.

Comment: Why does clojure allow single argument for `<`?  Why not?

Comment: Mathematically you need a pair to establish an ordering. So you're correct in that sense. But it's more practical to say an element of one is monotone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you consider 'monotonically decreasing' to be the same as 'are there any values after the first that are greater than the previous (to which we would reject this as a monotonically decreasing series)', then a single argument to both `>` (and `<` if you say increasing/less than) fulfil this definition.

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a better reason, but a simple one is this: say you got a list from someplace and you want to check that its ordered, you could simply do:

```
(let [ls (list-from-somplace)]
  (apply < ls)
```

If clojure didnt support 1 argument for `<` function, you would have to manually check the length of the list, making the code slightly uglier :)

## Edit

mars made a good point, we still need to handle the empty list, introducing ugliness:

```
(let [ls (list-from-someplace)]
  (when ls (apply < ls)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Clojure operators that can take indefinitely many arguments often accept as few as zero or one, if it makes sense to do so. For example,

```
(+) ;0
```

As @Mars points out, it's surprising that `>` doesn't have a zero arity returning `true`. Arity one returning `true` is what you'd expect.

Logically, *for all ...* includes the case where there aren't any, in this case, neighbouring pairs.